# Is it possible to change default directory for WinPython Command Prompt.exe?

Tags: python, windows

When I run "WinPython Command Prompt.exe", the working directory defaults to the scripts directory of the installation.

Creating a shortcut to run the exe with a specific working directory does not seem to have an effect.

Is it possible to have the directory after running "WinPython Command Prompt.exe" be something other than the scripts directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exe runs cmd.bat in the scripts directory.
It doesn't seem like the exe is passing "start in" or any parameters along.

To change the default start directory I modified cmd.bat instead:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0env_for_icons.bat"
cmd.exe /k cd /d d:\python
```

Update:

second possibility is to pass all arguments in cmd.bat:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0env_for_icons.bat"
cmd.exe /k %*
```

After that you can create a customized shortcut with the Target:
"C:\WPy64-3870\WinPython Command Prompt.exe" cd /d d:\python

Answer (score 0):

on latest version, drag&drop your directory over the icon, it should make your day.